# Deleting Specific Cache Files

Tags: php, mysql, caching

As you know, [ezSql](http://justinvincent.com/ezsql) has a useful caching feature.
I'm newly using this but when i edit anything on database, i'm deleting all cached files, and waiting for caching them again.

I'll explain it with an example,
There is a page (*http://domain.com/user.php?u=username*) which listing user's datas (username, city, phone etc..) .

I'm caching all queries on **user.php** file and all users' datas caching seperately. When some user (John) update own datas. When this happened, i'm deleting all cache files, so i'm deleting all user's cached datas. Are there any way to deleted (or refresh) **only John's** datas cache?

What do you think, is it possible ? You know cache files names is hashed (like this: *6f3b84011a8693ad7e5b86c6dff3d27d* )

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe so. The caching scheme in ezSQL is very limited. However, if you set up a separate directory for each set of queries you want to cache, you could only delete those that are specific.